# Is possible to increase the size of ActionBarDrawerToggle (Drawer menu)?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer, drawertoggle

I followed [ActionBarDrawerToggle GUIDE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html)

And I know how to show the icon of drawer on Action Bar by using `drawerImageRes` in this.

> public ActionBarDrawerToggle (Activity activity, DrawerLayout
>   drawerLayout, int drawerImageRes, int openDrawerContentDescRes, int
>   closeDrawerContentDescRes)
>
> The Activity hosting the drawer drawerLayout
>
> The DrawerLayout to link to the given Activity's ActionBar
>
> drawerImageRes    A Drawable resource to use as the drawer indicator
>
> openDrawerContentDescRes  A String resource to describe the "open drawer" action for accessibility
>
> closeDrawerContentDescRes A String resource to describe the "close drawer" action for accessibility

But `the icon looks like so small`,

So I want know `Is possible to increase the Drawer icon size?`

People help me please,

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, I need research about Action Bar first.

Add this :

```
<style name="Theme.white_style" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarSize">64dp</item>
        <item name="actionBarSize">64dp</item>
</style>
```

It worked!

*p/s : According to [Iconography](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html#action-bar), define height matched the specification for the action bar icons, which is 32 x 32 dp.*

> mdpi   - 32 dp = 32 px
>
> hdpi   - 32 dp * 1.5 = 48 px
>
> xxhdpi - 32 dp * 2 = 64 px

[Extra reference](http://code2care.org/pages/change-height-of-android-actionbar/)

Comment: This changes the size of the entire Action Bar and all its contents, not just the icon though.

Comment: yes, since Icon use "wrap_content", so it depends on size of entire Action bar.

Answer (score 3):

A great answer implemented which is a slight adjustment from this https://stackoverflow.com/a/40774724/3485872

First you want to create a custom class which extends the Drawable class which creates the hamburger and navigation icons. There are various methods to change the size of either but below are the methods which control the hamburger icon.

```
public class HamburgerDrawable extends DrawerArrowDrawable{

public HamburgerDrawable(Context context){
    super(context);
    setColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas){
    super.draw(canvas);

    setBarLength(30.0f);
    setBarThickness(5.0f);
    setGapSize(5.0f);

}
}
```

Then to call it from your class simply use:

```
private void increaseHamburgerSize(){
    mDrawerToggle.setDrawerArrowDrawable(new HamburgerDrawable(this));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you construct a new ActionBarDrawerToggle one of the parameters is the drawerImageRes. If you want this resource to be larger, try editing this resource (usually R.drawable.ic_drawer) and increasing its size.

Answer (score 1):

You can define attributes using the following styles. It will produce a larger hamburger button, and Back arrow icon.

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
</style>

<!-- This is the Global style for the NavigationDrawer toggle -->
<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <!--        Set that the nav buttons will animate -->
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    <!--       Set the bar length -->
    <item name="barLength">64dp</item>
    <!--        Set the space between the hamburger button bars -->
    <item name="gapBetweenBars">12dp</item>
    <!--        Set the thickness of the bar -->
    <item name="thickness">@dimen/half_default_gap</item>
    <!--        Set the color of the toggle button -->
    <item name="color">@color/colorToolbarTitleText</item>

    <!-- Here's how you increase the size of the back arrow icon. -->
    <item name="arrowHeadLength">@dimen/one_and_half_default_gap</item>
    <item name="arrowShaftLength">64dp</item>
</style>
```