# How can I change the actionbardrawertoggle icon, android?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, actionbardrawertoggle

In my activity I want to change the drawer toggle icon
I have my toolbar

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/appColor"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:theme="@style/MyDarkToolbarStyle">


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

This is the toolbar theme

```
 <style name="MyDarkToolbarStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
    <!--<item name="popupTheme">@style/PopupMenuStyle</item>-->
    <item name="actionButtonStyle">@style/MyActionButtonStyle</item>

</style>
```

This is the activity theme

```
 <style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/ColorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Is this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27028571/how-to-replace-the-hamburger-icon-used-for-actionbartoggle-on-android-toolbar-wi helps you?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use below code snippet to set your custom actionbar toggle button.

```
  mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);

            // mDrawerToggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.menu_icon);
            mToolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.menu_icon);

            mToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
                }
            });
```