# How to increase the size of Humburger icon which is create from setSupportActionBar

Tags: android

I want the button like in this picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPbkL.jpg

]public class NavigationDrawer extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

```
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle;
private Toolbar toolbar;
private NavigationView navigationView;
private TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation_drawer);

    textView=findViewById(R.id.text_view);

    toolbar=findViewById(R.id.tool);
    toolbar.setTitle("");

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    drawerLayout=findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    navigationView=findViewById(R.id.drawer);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    toggle=new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,toolbar,
            open,R.string.close);

    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();






}



@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
    String itemName= (String) menuItem.getTitle();
    textView.setText(itemName);
    closeDrawer();
    return true;
}
public void closeDrawer()
{
    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
}
public  void openDrawer()
{
    drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START))
    {
        closeDrawer();
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

}

This is my code please tell me how to increase the size of navigation drawer button which is humburger button. I tried different solutions but it did not worked

Answer (score 0):

You can override the default size of icon navigation drawer like this ( in dimens.xml )

```
<dimen name="design_navigation_icon_size" tools:override="true">XXdp</dimen>
```

Replace XX with your own value in dp

Comment: Did you try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28152018/change-the-size-of-hamburger-icon-in-toolbar#answer-39130176