# Android-How do I change the size of the ActionBarDrawerToggle Icon?

Tags: android

I want to make ActionBarDrawerToggle(Hamburger) Icon bigger.

I have try changing the width of  bar, but it can't change.

And what should I do?

Comment: share your code here.

Comment: @VedPrakash The problem has been solved,thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < mToolbar.getChildCount(); i++) {
   if(mToolbar.getChildAt(i) instanceof ImageButton){
       mToolbar.getChildAt(i).setScaleX(1.5f);
       mToolbar.getChildAt(i).setScaleY(1.5f);
   }
}
```

Comment: @hengchen Cheers!

Comment: This did not work for me. But this answer did work.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23896617/is-possible-to-increase-the-size-of-actionbardrawertoggle-drawer-menu

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Yaw's Answer.

You should write like this:

```
toolbar.post(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < toolbar.getChildCount(); i++) {
            if(toolbar.getChildAt(i) instanceof ImageButton){
                toolbar.getChildAt(i).setScaleX(1.5f);
                toolbar.getChildAt(i).setScaleY(1.5f);
            }
        }
    }
});
```